# Count occurrences of value in multiple sub dirs

Tags: bash

How do i script following to count please I have a directory structure below

```
dir1/diskname 
dir2/diskname
dir3/diskname
dir4/diskname
```

diskname contains a value:

```
hitachi
samsung
LG
```

I would like a script to scan each dir look in diskname and count the value

For example if the file in dir1,2,4 was hitachi and 3 was samsung result would be

```
hitachi 3
samsung 1
```

Comment: What have you tried on your own?

Comment: OK so far i have managed

for i in {0..10}
do
vendor=$(cat /directory$i/device/diskname)

If it was single result i know i would have just used grep | wc -l

Comment: Use `cat` with a glob to output all the text files at once and pipe the result to `sort | uniq -c`

Comment: Sorry i don't understand glob

Comment: I'm not going to chew your food for you. You need to conduct some research on your own.

Comment: Not asking you to but remember we all start somewhere, remember where you came from i did google glob nothing helpful. Thanks for your time all the same.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Panki [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642916/count-occurrences-of-value-in-multiple-sub-dirs/642925#comment1203744_642916):

```bsh
cat dir*/diskname | sort | uniq -c
```

This would concatenate all the `diskname` files into one stream using `cat`. The `sort` utility then sorts this data and `uniq -c` counts how many time each line occurs consecutively.

In the general case, when there are *many thousands* of `diskname` files, the `cat` command would fail with an "argument list too long" error since the filename globbing pattern `dir*/diskname` would expand to too many pathnames.  In this case, you could choose to loop over all files instead:

```bsh
for name in dir*/diskname
do
    cat "$name"
done | sort | uniq -c
```

or, you could use `find` (assuming the current directory is where all the `dir*` directories are found):

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 2 -path './dir*/diskname' -type f -exec cat {} + | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: OP probably needs a recursive glob (`**/*`) , judging from the comments

Comment: @Panki I don't think so. That comment was probably just them not knowing what you meant when you said the word "glob".  Or are you referring to `cat /directory$i/device/diskname`? Well, that's not in the actual question.

Comment: I thank you @Panki the first single line suggestion worked like a charm. I offer you many positive vibes for what it's worth.